# can't display a complete value from a variable in php form using PostgreSQL query

Tags: php, postgresql, escaping

(beginner) Despite the use of many forums, I can't find a solution.
I query PostgreSQL and try to display the result in a text field of a php page.

The query:

```
$sql3 = "select * from matable where code_tranche = $1" ;
```

then

```
$marequete = pg_query_params(pg_connect("host=$server port=$port dbname=$base user=$_SESSION[identifier] password=$_SESSION[password]"),
 $sql3, array($code_tranche)) ;
```

Then, the html:

```
<body class = "imagemenuu">
<div >
<form >
<h4>Operation <?php echo $code_tranche ?></h4>
<?php
    if (pg_num_rows($marequete) ==0) {
     echo "<h5> The operation "$code_tranche' does not exist </h5>" ;
    }
    else {
    line = pg_fetch_assoc($marequete) ;
    var_dump($line[nomope]) ;
    }
?>
<p class="psga" >operation name: <input type="text" size='60' name="nom_ope" value=<?php echo"'$ligne[nomope]'" ; ?> class = "alert alert-info" >   
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

As written, the field nom_ope displays the contents of the field name of the variable $line unless the field contains an **'** ex: **phase 110**, very well but **L** instead of **L'hopital**.

I've tried:

```
echo $ligne[nomope]
```

result: **L'hopital** but just **phase**.

```
addslashes($line[nomope])
```

no better than **L'\hopital**.

```
htmlentities($line[name], ENT_QUOTES)
```

not better either.

```
value=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ligne[nomope]) ; ?>
```

no way...

In short, depending on the functions used, either I have the entire field and nothing after an **'**, or I have the text with the **'** and just the first word of the field for the other cases. :o

Which technique will allow me to have the entire result, **'** or not?

Comment: You should put proper quotes around the attribute value to begin with, and escape whichever attribute delimiter you use (double or single quotes) inside the value. Go check the second parameter for `htmlspecialchars`. (And PostgreSQL has nothing in particular to do with this to begin with, you would have the same problem with the data coming from any other source.)

Comment: Make the debugging  little simpler and dont run functions into each other. [`pg_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) and [`pg_query_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php)

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten **"** in attribute :
so now :

```
value="<?php echo $ligne['nomope'] ; ?>"
```

It works fine.